# How to find intersect elements of concatenated string?

Tags: r, string

```
# create sample df
basket_customer <- c("apple,orange,banana","apple,banana,orange","strawberry,blueberry")
basket_ideal<- c("orange,banana","orange,apple,banana","strawberry,watermelon")
customer_name <- c("john","adam","john")
visit_id <- c("1001","1001","1003")

df2 <- cbind.data.frame(basket_customer,basket_ideal,customer_name,visit_id)

df2$basket_ideal <- as.character(basket_ideal)

df2$basket_customer <- as.character(basket_customer)
```

The goal is to compare the basket elements (fruits) of each customer to the ideal basket and return the missing fruit.

Note the same visit_id can exists for 1 or more users so the uniqueID is (id+username) and elements are not alphabetically sorted.

**expected output:**

| visit_id | customer_name | NOT_in_basket_ideal | NOT_in_basket_customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | john | apple | NA |
| 1001 | adam | NA | NA |
| 1003 | john | blueberry | watermelon |

I tried using row_wise(),intersect(),except(),and unnesting however did not succeed. Thank you

Comment: You should post code that creates these objects and explain why this was tagged [sqldf]. (Not my downvote, but I'm sure that the downvoter was unhappy because you were not providing a [MCVE].

Comment: @IRTFM This is how the data given in an excel file from another team, cant reproduce it or change how its given. sqldf tag is added to give an option to solve it via SQL if its easier to use set operation. However I was not successful

Comment: Pictures are not good ways to present material on SO. If those pictures are portions of a screenshot of a print representations of an R data object, then post text from `dput(object_name)`. If they are still in Excel, then you need to search on methods of importing from Excel rather than asking how to manipulate R objects.

Comment: @IRTFM, thank you, I removed the picture,. hope this is more correct

Comment: Your posted question mentioned that the columns are `list`.  Now.  it looks like it is just a string concatenated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `Map` to loop over the corresponding elements of the `list` columns, and use `setdiff` to get the elements of the first vector not in the second

```
cst_list <- strsplit(df2$basket_customer, ",\\s*") 
idl_list <- strsplit(df2$basket_ideal, ",\\s*")
lst1 <- Map(function(x, y) if(identical(x, y)) 'equal' 
       else setdiff(x, y), cst_list, idl_list)
lst1[lengths(lst1) == 0] <- NA_character_
v1 <- sapply(lst1, toString)
```

and the second case, just reverse the order

```
lst2 <- Map(function(x, y) if(identical(x, y)) 'equal' 
      else setdiff(y, x), cst_list, idl_list)  
lst2[lengths(lst2) == 0] <- NA_character_
v2 <- sapply(lst2, toString)
```

---

Combining the output from both to 'df2'

```
df2[c("NOT_in_basket_ideal", "NOT_in_basket_customer")] <- list(v1, v2)
```

-output

```
df2[-(1:2)]
#  customer_name visit_id NOT_in_basket_ideal NOT_in_basket_customer
#1          john     1001               apple                     NA
#2          adam     1001                  NA                     NA
#3          john     1003           blueberry             watermelon
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df2 %>% 
   mutate(across(starts_with('basket'), ~ str_extract_all(., "\\w+"))) %>%
   transmute(customer_name, visit_id, 
     NOT_in_basket_ideal = map2_chr(basket_customer, 
          basket_ideal, ~ toString(setdiff(.x, .y))), 
     NOT_in_basket_customer = map2_chr(basket_ideal, basket_customer,
           ~ toString(setdiff(.x, .y))))
#  customer_name visit_id NOT_in_basket_ideal NOT_in_basket_customer
#1          john     1001               apple                       
#2          adam     1001                                           
#3          john     1003           blueberry             watermelon
```

Comment: hi, I updated the question to provide more clarity of the desired output. your solution only works if both baskets are identical.

Comment: @TAHIR It is because your description was that the columns were `list` instead of vectors.  I split the columns and changed the code

Comment: Thank you, I apologise for my previous wrong explanation. how can I get a result as a df with the corresponding visit_id, customer_name as shown above ?

Comment: @TAHIR you may not have checked my updated solution.  Please check the update in my post

Comment: your first solution with out the tidyverse worked better however on my real data some cells end up with 2 elements so afterwards I just used seperate_rows() and all results were correct. Thank for your help.